# jQuery field update before form submit fails - javascript variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, callback, scope

I need to update a (hidden) form field before submit.
I tried all possible implementations but the changed value simply doesn't get submitted -> the old value is submitted instead
The field I want to update is 'XXX_place'
I set it to '' first to delete old value:

```
$('#XXX_place').val('');
```

this code checks whether it's updated:

```
if ($('#XXX_place').val() == '') {
        event.preventDefault();
}
```

the form is not submitted becouse the condition is true but the field is updated and has the right value -> that's very confusing

My latest guess is it's variable scope - everything what's done inside

> function(results, status) {

is not set globaly and although my field is updated the result is not submitted. What should I change?

here the complete code:

```
    var geocoder;
var placeData;
geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var input = document.getElementById('XXX_address'),
        options = {
            types: ['geocode'],
            language: ['de'],
            componentRestrictions: {country: 'de'}
        },
        autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);

$('#searchform').submit(function(event) {
    codeAddress();
    if ($('#XXX_place').val() == '') {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});


function codeAddress() {
    $('#XXX_place').val('');
    placeData = '';
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(48.257141, 11.335030),
        new google.maps.LatLng(48.014731, 11.828041));
    geocoder.geocode( { 'componentRestrictions':{'locality': 'Munich'},
        'bounds': bounds, 'address': $('#XXX_address').val()}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            placeData = stringifyPlace(results[0].formatted_address, results[0].geometry.location);
            $('#XXX_place').val(placeData);
            }
     });

      alert(placeData);
}

function stringifyPlace(address, location) {

    return JSON.stringify({"formatted_address": address,
                                    "latitude": location.d,
                                    "longitude": location.e
                                    });
}
```

Comment: The case of the Asynchronous request being treated as synchronous.

Comment: what does it mean? is my idea possible to realize or do I need to change everything?

Comment: It means `$('#XXX_place').val(placeData);` runs after `if ($('#XXX_place').val() == '') `. So yes, you need to change how you are doing things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript does not act like most scripting-laguages you might know. It heavily depends on callback functions (handler) to avoid into running issues like this one.

On submit you are calling codeAdress() in which you call the geocode method. That method seems to use an ajax call. JavaScript doesn't care whether or not that call has completed it just goes on with submitting.

You might get around this with binding a click event handler to the submit button, instead of listening to the submit. You would have to prevent default and trigger submit in geocoders callback function like so:

```
$('#id_of_submit_button').click(function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 codeAdress();

 return false;
});
```

and

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'componentRestrictions':{'locality': 'Munich'},
                    'bounds': bounds, 'address': $('#XXX_address').val()}, 
                    function(results, status) {
                      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        placeData = stringifyPlace(results[0].formatted_address,
                        results[0].geometry.location);
                        $('#XXX_place').val(placeData);
                        $('#searchform').submit();
                      }
                     });
```

Another possibility is handling your submit with a boolean var.

```
var val_unchanged = false;

// some code

$('#searchform').submit(function(e){
  if val_unchanged{
    e.preventDefault
    codeAdress();
    return false;
  }else{
    return true;
  }
});

// add at the end of geocode callback
val_unchanged = false;
$('#searchform').submit();
```

You might be better off not relying on a form though and submit your data manualy.